# Need to write an algorithm for getting sum of values from Array 1 values for each Array 2 value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am  creating a algorithm to match any combination of cells of first array to second array value with priority in second array. for example in javascript :

```
var arr=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
var arr2=[100,120,140];
```

what I want is to define into following logic(priority for value of second array's cell serially) automatically and please help me finding pseudo for algorithm

```
100 = 10+20+30+40 //arr2[0] = arr1[0] + arr1[1] + arr1[2] + arr1[3]
120 = 50+70 //arr2[1] = arr1[4] + arr1[6]
140 = 60+80 //arr2[2] = arr1[5] + arr1[7]
90 = 90  //remaining arr1[8]
```

values are demo and can be changed dynamically.

Comment: Both arrays will be sorted? What have you tried till now?

Comment: Remove the language tags, if you only want an alogrithm.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Just a little clarification, when you compare the two arrays what you want is the values from the second array, with any values in the first which when added don't equal one of the values in the second?

Comment: Yes, @John Halbert, exactly what you said, sorry for my English. I just want to specifies combination of first array values to get second array values.

Comment: Hi, @user1147987. please continue your demo. I don't understand. is it [100,120,140,90...] or?

Comment: actually second array [100,120,140] will be focused for each value inside second array, it needs to sum any value of first array without overlap so after all of the value in second array, 90 is left.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is possible if you take both array as sorted array and then start adding elements from last ends of first array (array1)  which are the greatest as array is sorted , now check if sum matches then proceed else if sum is lesser than element in array2 you were checking then you need to add third element from array1. Another case if sum is greater than element in array2 then you have to neglect one of the element from array1 you have used in addition and replace the addition with the previous element you HV used from array one. Repeat the steps.  You need to think how to do this correctly or else you need to share some of your work or logic u r thinking , so that we can help

Comment: This is very complex, and this solution needs much more elaboration to be correct.  For example, we start by summing each array and finding the difference.  Starting from the last index of array 1 we begin adding values.  If we find the sum is greater than the difference at any one point, we must skip that value.  But if we don't find that the sum is equal to the difference by the beginning we need to start over from the end, skipping the 2nd to last value.  Then the 3rd to last, then 4th.  What's more we will eventually need to select out values -1, -3, -5 then -1, -4, -2 and so on.

Comment: But I believe this solution is on the right track.  Any mathematicians here?  This would be a perfect place for their expertise.

Answer (score 0):

As the matter is quite complex, over and above sufficing on a pseudo code style explanation, I have also coded a practical implementation that you may find at this [link](https://repl.it/BEzQ/2).

I advise you to refrain from looking at the solution and first try to implement the algorithm yourself as there is a lot of scope for further improvement.

Here is in broad lines an explanation to the way I have decided to tackle the algorithm:

The problem presented by the OP is related to a classic example of distributing `n` unique elements over `k` unique boxes.
In this case here, `arr` has 9 unique elements that need to be distributed over three distinct spots, represented by the container: `arr2`.
So the first step in tackling this problem is to figure out how you can implement a function that given `n` and `k`, is able to calculate all the possible distributions that apply.

The closest that I could come up with was the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind, which is [defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) as:

> The number of ways of partitioning a set of n elements into m nonempty sets (i.e., m set blocks), also called a Stirling set number. For example, the set {1,2,3} can be partitioned into three subsets in one way: {{1},{2},{3}}; into two subsets in three ways: {{1,2},{3}}, {{1,3},{2}}, and {{1},{2,3}}; and into one subset in one way: {{1,2,3}}.

If you pay close attention to the example provided, you will realize that it pertains to the enumeration of all the distribution combinations possible over INDISTINGUISHABLE partitions as order doesn't matter.
Since in our case, each spot in the container `arr2` represents a UNIQUE spot and order therefore does matter, we will thus be required to enumerate all the Stirling Combinations over every possible combination of `arr2`.
Practically speaking, this means that for our example where `arr2.length === 3`, we will be required to apply all of the Stirling Combinations obtained to `[100,120,140]`, `[120,140,100]`, `[140,100,120]` etc.(in total 6 permutations)

The main challenging part here is to implement the Stirling Function, but luckily somebody has already done so:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/03/24/10510315.aspx

After copy and pasting the Stirling Function and using it to distribute `arr` over 3 unique spots, you now need to filter out the distributions that don't sum up to the designated spots encompassed by `arr2`.

This will then leave you with all the possible solutions that apply. In your case, for 
    var arr=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
    var arr2=[100,120,140];
no solutions apply at all.

A quick workaround to that is by expanding the distribution target `arr2` from `[100,120,140]` to `[100,120,140,90]`. A better workaround is that in the case zero solutions are found, then take away one element from list `arr` until you obtain a solution. Then you can later on expand your solution sets by including this element where it represents a mapping of it unto itself.